# plotly and counter python cant get result

Tags: python, plotly, scapy, counting

To get destination port result from the pcap to the plotly, I can't get any result to plotly chart, but if I do print (dport) can list the dport result, anything wrong on my python?

```
from scapy.all import *
import plotly
from collections import Counter
ReadPacket = rdpcap("Subnet192.pcap")

dstPORT=[]
for pkt in ReadPacket:
   if pkt.haslayer("TCP"):
      try:
         ddport = pkt["TCP"].dport
      except:
         pass

cnt=Counter()
for TCP in dstPORT:
        cnt[ddport]+= 1

xData=[]
yData=[]
for ddport, count in cnt.most_common():
        xData.append(dport)
        yData.append(count)
plotly.offline.plot({
         "data":[plotly.graph_objs.Bar(x=xData, y=yData)])
          })
```